# Crawled page screenshot for Angular site is blank in the Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, angular

I set up a SPA page through [Angular](https://angular.io/), and achieved the effect of Server Side Render through [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron), In the [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.careline.com.tw%2FCareLineCar%2Fcar&locale=en_US), I could get my dynamically generated Meta data, but the preview of Google Console Search was blank

I understand that Googlebot can dynamically render the DOM itself , but why is it always blank? is there something wrong with the structure of my HTML?

**Facebook Debug Tool**
[image]

**Google Search Console**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Through this issue, I found a way to solve it

[It looks like angular.io may no longer be indexing](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21272)

> Angular can be indexed by the Googlebot without using server-side
>   render way.

**How to debug**

add the following code to your `index.html`, and then open **Google Search Console** to crawler it.

you can debug by the error msg that the user agent is **GoogleBot**

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/debug-rendering

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    var errorText = [
        // key point of debug
        'UserAgent: ' + navigator.userAgent ,
        e.message,
        'URL: ' + e.filename,
        'Line: ' + e.lineno + ', Column: ' + e.colno,
        'Stack: ' + (e.error && e.error.stack || '(no stack trace)')
    ].join('\n');

    // Example: log errors as visual output into the host page.
    // Note: you probably don’t want to show such errors to users, or
    //       have the errors get indexed by Googlebot; however, it may
    //       be a useful feature while actively debugging the page.
    var DOM_ID = 'rendering-debug-pre';
    if (!document.getElementById(DOM_ID)) {
        var log = document.createElement('pre');
        log.id = DOM_ID;
        log.style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap';
        log.textContent = errorText;
        if (!document.body) document.body = document.createElement('body');
        document.body.insertBefore(log, document.body.firstChild);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(DOM_ID).textContent += '\n\n' + errorText;
    }

    // Example: log the error to remote service.
    // Note: you can log errors to a remote service, to understand
    //       and monitor the types of errors encountered by regular users,
    //       Googlebot, and other crawlers.
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('POST', 'https://example.com/logError');
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
    client.send(errorText);

});
```

**Possible reasons**

**1. Unused polyfill**

@[MrCroft](/MrCroft)

uncomment the following line under 
`/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/`:

---

**2. Upgrade to latest Angular version**

it makes it easier for you to identify possible problems

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21272#issuecomment-370153525